# phroute not working properly saying route not defined

Tags: php, routes

I am using phroute .

When i used project name as route then it work for root route. But if i used "/" , or something . Then the route not working .

This route is worked like root route.

```
/*this is working as root route like / */ 
$router->controller('/ecommerce', \App\Controllers\HomeController::class);
```

This route is not working . And says that by telling this project name this route is not defined. like "The ecommerce route is not defined"

```
/* If i run this route it shows , that ecomeerce route not found. */
$router->controller('/', \App\Controllers\HomeController::class);
```

My Full code is here .

```
<?php

use Phroute\Phroute\Dispatcher;

use Phroute\Phroute\Exception\HttpMethodNotAllowedException;
use Phroute\Phroute\Exception\HttpRouteNotFoundException;
use Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector;
use Phroute\Phroute\RouteParser;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$router = new RouteCollector(new RouteParser());

/*this is working as root route like / */ 
$router->controller('/ecommerce', \App\Controllers\HomeController::class);

/* If i run this route it shows , that ecomeerce route not found. */
$router->controller('/', \App\Controllers\HomeController::class);

$router->controller('/ecommerce/users', \App\Controllers\UsersController::class);

$dispatcher = new Dispatcher($router->getData());

try {
    $response = $dispatcher->dispatch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],

    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));

}   catch (HttpRouteNotFoundException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

    die();
} catch (HttpMethodNotAllowedException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

    die();`enter code here`
}
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are accessing the URL of the app as "http://localhost/ecommerce", so you need to add "/ecommerce".

Normally when you host your application to a proper domain, the app is accessed without the "ecommerce" part.
It's always better to use a virtual host in your dev environment to fix this issue.